# Error creating virtual smart card in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am getting an error while trying Windows Phone 8.1 (devpreview) and its support for Virtual Smart Cards.

Running RequestVirtualSmartCardCreationAsync on my Nokia Lumia Icon i get a generic System.UnauthorzedAccessException with message

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Code used

```
SmartCardPinPolicy pinPolicy = new SmartCardPinPolicy();
pinPolicy.MinLength = 6;

IBuffer adminkey = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(24);

SmartCardProvisioning provisioning = await
SmartCardProvisioning.RequestVirtualSmartCardCreationAsync(
         "My Test Virtual SmartCard",
         adminkey,
         pinPolicy, Guid.NewGuid());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable `Shared User Certificates` in the Capabilities-section of the Appxmanifest.